# PySpark: writing in 'append' mode and overwrite if certain criteria match

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, append, amazon-redshift

I am append the following Spark dataframe to an existing Redshift database. And I want to use 'month' and 'state' as criterias to check, and replace data in the Redshift table if `month = '2021-12' and state = 'ga'`

dataframe we want to append: `df`

| month | state | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12 | ca | ho0 |
| 2021-12 | ca | ho1 |
| 2021-12 | ca | ho2 |
| 2021-12 | ca | ho3 |
| 2021-12 | ca | ho4 |
| 2021-12 | ga | ho5 |
| 2021-12 | ga | ho6 |
| 2021-12 | ga | ho7 |
| 2021-12 | ga | ho8 |
| 2021-12 | ga | ho9 |

I've tried the following script to append it, looks like it only append `df` dataframe, without replacing (overwriting) existing records for month '2021-12' and state 'ga'.

```
df.write \
  .format("xxx") \
  .option("url", "xxx") \
  .option("dbtable", "table1") \
  .option("tempdir", "xxxx") \
  .option("aws_iam_role", "xxxx") \
  .mode("append") \
  .option("replaceWhere", "month == '2021-12' AND state == 'ga'") \
  .save()
```

I guess `.option("replaceWhere", "month == '2021-12' AND state == 'ga'")`  is not working. How can I make the change? thanks!
(I also tried the following part, looks like existing records are gone, and replaced by `df`)

```
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("replaceWhere", "month == '2021-12' AND state == 'ga'") \
```

Comment: Since I am using databricks, it doesn't support this kind of partially update / overwrite; need to rely on Delta Lake currently trying: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#language-python

Comment: Not sure your viewpoint is correct

Answer (score 1):

`replaceWhere`  This option works almost like a dynamic overwrite partition, basically you are telling Spark to overwrite only the data that is on those range partitions. In addition, data will be saved only if your dataframe matches the condition `replaceWhere`, otherwise, if a single row does not match, an exception Data written out does not match `replaceWhere` will be thrown. You an ref [link](https://mungingdata.com/delta-lake/updating-partitions-with-replacewhere/)
.If you want to handle same scenario within partition , you can use `MERGE INTO` .

Comment: Thanks i guess I used that function but originally not in Delta Lake, but that's helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spark cannot do data merge with Redshift directly, since we are using Databricks, it provide 'Delta Lake' as an environment to do data upsert / merge, then we write the table from Delta Lake to Redshift.
https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#language-python

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this link below when working with Redshift. A little more than you need, but applicable. The link shows UPSERT simulation. The link is
http://www.silota.com/blog/amazon-redshift-upsert-support-staging-table-replace-rows/

Even inserting to Redshift is not a Spark thing, I have posted on this in the past. One uses COPY from s3 standardly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! That seems to be alternative approach besides mine using Databricks platform.

Comment: sorry we don't want to rely on SQL at the moment though it's applicable, thank you for your suggest but cannot accept it since I am looking for a Spark related solution.

Comment: Well not many do that.

Comment: True lol but thanks